# undefined method `each' because param[“value”] is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm creating a project in ruby on rail where create a scream with the following route the postman:

votar contra
favorita
Estou criando um projeto em ruby on rail onde crio um grito com a seguinte rota no postman:

```
POST:http://localhost:3000/api/yells
{
    "user_id":"1",
    "title":"caneca",
    "desciption":"beber",
    "yell_type":"oferta",
    "price":"20,00",
    "categories":[{"name":"porcelana"}]
}
```

controller #create

```
def create
  #@yell = Yell.new(yell_params.except(:categories))
  @yell = Yell.new({title: params[:title], desciption: params[:desciption], price: params[:price], user_id: params[:user_id], yell_type: params[:yell_type]})

  params[:categories].each do |rel|
    @category = Category.find_by_name(rel[:name])
    if @category
      #only creates the relationship
    else
      @yell.categories.build(name: rel[:name]) #creates the relationship and category
    end
  end

  if @yell.save
    render json: @yell, status: :created, location: api_yell_path(@yell)
  else
    render json: @yell.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

However'm doing a project with a friend of mine who is doing the frontend, and when he tests in his machine by the postman, replacing localhost for my ip, of the error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Perhaps the error is generated in this line:

```
params[:categories].each do |rel|
```

I guess it's because the params[:categories] is coming void, but it was not to come. Not least because in my machine and it works not.

Comment: "Perhaps the error is generated in this line:" You don't have to guess which line it's coming from. The error message will give you a complete stack trace which tells you exactly which line the error occurs on.

Comment: Your guess is probably right, you can verify it in stacktrace. Put a debugger inside 'def create' and check the params that you are getting when your friend makes the api call. Also ask your friend to try the api call using curl instead of postman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is telling you exactly where the problem is. When a key in a Ruby hash does not hold a value, `nil` is returned. To help solve this issue, you can replace:

```
params[:categories]
```

with

```
Array(params[:categories])
```

to help the `each` block not error.

Comment: So @yes, is working but not as expected, but it creates all the values in both yell fields, as in the category are empty. For some reason what is being spent on my POST is not coming in my parameters.

Comment: I would check the actual params inside the `create` method to see what is missing.

Comment: My method create within the controller is just what I posted, have any place where I have to start params?

Comment: I would either `puts` or place a debugger like `pry` at the top of your `create` method to see which params your server is actually getting.

Comment: Sorry guy'm new to Ruby, what's that `pry` and how to use it to do what you ta asking me?

Comment: `pry` is a debugging tool. I was simply suggesting that you catch the parameters and actually print them out to see what is going on. That might help you.

Comment: discovered thanks for the tip, my colleague was forgetting to put in the header `content-type = aplication/json`